# Peak detection for signals that contain high frequencies

Tags: sound, impulse-response, peak-detection

I have an question about peak detection. My purpose is creating a plot with an impulse response and the decay line at / above it.
What I see till now is that there are two options for finding peaks:

- the simplest version is to just compare point with the points beside it 
  $ f(n-1) , f(n) , f(n+1) $
- The other assumes that there are at least 3 or 4 points per half wave ([DSP related peak detection](https://www.dsprelated.com/freebooks/sasp/Peak_Detection_Steps_3.html))

But my simple self recorded sweeps and transfer function generate just a impulse response with high frequencies. So the peak with option 1 is a peak of the highest sample value but isn't necessarily the highest audio peak.
Also the situation with 3 or 4 samples don't exist.

[image: The blue line is something i want to accomplish]

I'm not looking to a complete answer or work around(however examples are fine). Some links or names from papers would be nice.

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question. "Creating a plot", "decay line", "finding peaks", "high frequencies", "sweeps" are all terms I am familiar with, but I cannot put the puzzle together. Perhaps a hand-drawing of what you really wish?

Comment: I add a picture where in I try to explain what i want

Comment: What is the background of that? Do you want to match exponential decay to your IR?

Comment: Yes and maybe start point and end point for RT60. but first i have to find out if that's aloud...

Comment: OK, so you want to take whatever IR you have and calculate RT from it? And for that you want to match the decay? If so, then I have an easy solution for you.

Comment: That would be great

Comment: @jojek you said you had an 'easy' solution but after that you didn't respont anymore

Comment: Sorry, I haven’t seen your response. Will write the answer once I am at home.